# How to share files between 2 instances in different security groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group, wan

I have two instances in two private subnets associated to different security groups. How can I transfer files between them in an "NFS manner"?

Comment: What do you mean "nfs manner"? You can allow access from another sec group or open ports

Comment: That they have access to a certain directory of the other instance. I suppose we can do this with FTP, however I am not sure where to put the FTP server if I want a double-ended file transfer. Can a single instance be both a FTP server and a client? Should I use a bastion host instead as a FTP server between them?

Comment: All options are possible. However, when you mentioned NFS, maybe using AWS EFS could be an option. It is managed (you don't need to have a separate server) and can be shared between instances

Comment: Hey thanks! This is a great idea!! Just to confirm, this can be done for different security groups right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have two instances in two private subnets associated to different security groups.

In a security group you may specify as a source another security group. You can configure two groups to allow traffic from each other, but that creates a circular reference. It will work, but then it's cumbersome to automate or update the group configuration.

Better to create another sec-group trusting the traffic from itself (see how the *defaut* sg is created) and assign the new sec group the both instances (it is possible to assign multiple sg). Assuming the private subnets are in the same VPC.

> if I want a double-ended file transfer. Can a single instance be both a FTP server and a client? Should I use a bastion host instead as a FTP server between them?

You can have both instances serving as a client and server the same time, nothing wrong with that. However - if you want to have a shared, reliable and "NFS-like" transfer, I'd suggest using the [AWS EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) (or EFSx if using Windows) what is a managed NFS storage.